# mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

My error message is here

> mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in line 28
> and mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null
> given in line 29

My code

```
    <?php

    class Database{
    public $con;
    public $error;
    
    public function _construct(){
        $this->con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
        if(!$this->con)
        {
            echo "Database Connection Error" .mysqli_connect_error($this->con);
        }
    
    }
    public function login($data)
    {
        $username =$data['username'];
        $password =$data['password'];
        
        if($username=="" || $password=="")
        {
            $msg="Field must not be empty";
            return $msg;
        }
        else
        {
            $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_table where username = '$username' AND 
            password = '$password'";
            $result=mysqli_query($this->con,$query);
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $user = $row['username'];
            $pass = $row['password'];
            
            if($username==$user && $password==$pass)
            {
                header("Location: dashboard.php");
            }
            else
            {
                $msg="Username and Password not match";
                return $msg;
            }               
        }
    }
}
    ?>
```

Comment: could you please provide the output of `var_dump(mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db"));` ?

Comment: Check your query. 
Don't need to put ' ' befor and after variable in double quotes. Because in double-quotes, it will be parse string automatically.

Comment: thank u @ParthPatel but i still got the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo. It should be `__construct()` notice the extra `_`

Answer (score 0):

Pass another argument inside mysqli_fetch_array(), the second argument being the type of array you want to fetch(MYSQLI_ASSOC).So make it

```
mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Or another reason maybe that your mysqli_query is not returning anything. It can be because of some error in your query code. Try making that query in your mysql database and see if it works.